# A problem with installing lxml (Windows 10)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, compiler-errors, lxml

I was trying to install lxml for parsing data in Python. I could successfully install requests and beautifulsoup4, but when I tried lxml I got this error[[photo one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RatyE.png)]
[[photo two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDuJi.png)]
What can I do?

I tried to update pip, setuptools, and wheel, but nothing has changed

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)